# Checking collision if you have two velocity vectors and two 3D positions

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have two velocity vectors in 3D and their positions, how would I check if they are colliding in 3D without using bounding sphere or any other primitive.

```
const double tx = poi.Position().GetLongitude() - m_sPosAV.GetLongitude() / m_sVelAV.x - velocity.at(0).toDouble();
const double ty = poi.Position().GetAltitude() - m_sPosAV.GetAltitude() / m_sVelAV.y - velocity.at(1).toDouble();
const double tz = poi.Position().GetLatitude() - m_sPosAV.GetLatitude() / m_sVelAV.z - velocity.at(2).toDouble();

            if (tx == 0 || ty == 0 || tz == 0)
            {
                qDebug() << "collision ";
                return true;
            }

            if (tx && ty && tz)
            {

                if (tx == ty)
                {
                    qDebug() << "collision at that time ";
                    return true;
                }
                else if (tx == tz)
                {
                    qDebug() << "collision at that time";
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You get two lines and you have to check whether they have exactly one common point. You need basic analytic-geometric-tools for this. But note that a common point does not necessarily mean that a collision actually occurs. To check this you have to consider the time as well

Comment: @Peter Would you write the equations because I'm coding it in c++, and post it as an answer please

Comment: Also you will need to define what do you consider a collision as in the minimum distance of the two points, $d(p_1(x,y,z,t),p_2(x,y,z,t))$, so that a collision happens. You could try defining a collision as that distance is zero for point particles but not very useful in real-world particles where that distance being the diameter of the particles is commonly used (assuming they are same particles). The rest is just either solving the EoM (equation of motion) for both particles and checking whether such a collision exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, the starting points are $$a=\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3}$$ and $$b=\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2\\b_3}$$ and the velocities are $$u=\pmatrix{u_1\\u_2\\u_3}$$ and $$v=\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2\\v_3}$$

To find out whether a collision actually occurs, check whether there exists $t\in \mathbb R$ with $a+tu=b+tv$. If you want to know whether the lines have a common point, check whether there exist $s,t\in \mathbb R$ with $a+su=b+tv$

The second verification is not trivial to program in c++ , but the first is relatively easy : If $u=v$ , then a collision occurs if and only if $a=b$.

Otherwise find different components (for example $u_1$ and $v_1$) and calculate $t=\frac{b_1-a_1}{u_1-v_1}$ (the index could be $2$ or $3$) and verify whether $a_2+tu_2=b_2+tv_2$ and $a_3+tu_3=b_3+tv_3$ is satisfied

(Checking equality is problematic in a program, so verify that the absolute difference of two numbers is smaller than, lets say, $10^{-9}$ instead of verifying the equality directly)

Comment: As already mentioned , this verification is not very useful in practice, but the advantage is that it can be easily implemented. More effort is needed to calculate the minimal distance

Comment: is it possible to know the time of collision ?

Comment: Would you write a pseudo code please ?

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: @andre The $t$ I calculated is the time when the collision occurs

Comment: so its not enough to know from that T, that the collision is occured ?
is my code correct ?

Comment: Ah, I see. You calculated the time for each component and compared the times, right ? This is also possible. It is a bit difficult to see the formula. Your variables are somewhat long ... I think, paranthesis are missing. If you write $a-b/c-d$ the program calculates $a-(b/c)-d$, you have to write $(a-b)/(c-d)$ to calculate $\frac{a-b}{c-d}$

Comment: Thanks so much. I missed the parenthesis.

Comment: And better avoid to verify that $tx=ty$ or similar equations. I noticed in PARI/GP, for example that numbers with the same decimal visible expansion, can be interpreted as diffferent numbers. To avoid this, use a very small number and declare equalities to be true, when the difference of the numbers is smaller

Comment: What is PARI/GP ?

Comment: @andre A computational tool which can calculate with extremely high precision, for example numbers like $\pi$. It also has many useful numbertheoretical functions, but it can also be used for analysis-problems

Comment: Thanks so much I would vote up but I don't have enough points. Is the reset code is correct ? The conditions for tx,ty,tz ?

Comment: I have not much experience with c++ and the formulas with the long variables are somewhat hard to read. Just try some examples and check the result manually

Comment: I improved your reputation. Do you have other questions, which I can upvote ?

Comment: I reduced the variable names, http://pastebin.com/cEvCyMiA  Is everything correct ? The checks,..etc ?

Comment: Where is that equation of motion is derived from ? xnewA = xoldA+vxA*t; xnewB = xoldB+vxB*t; then xoldA + vxA*t = xoldB+vxB*t